# Генерация QR кода ZXing

Tags: c#, unity3d, qrcode, qr, zxing

Необходимо сгенерировать QR-код из текста. Использую библиотеку [ZXing.unity.dll](https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/tree/master/Clients/UnityDemo/Assets)

```
using ZXing;
using ZXing.QrCode;
```

Генерирую QR-код

```
private static Color32[] Encode(string textForEncoding, int width, int height) {
    var writer = new BarcodeWriter {
        Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,

        Options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions{
            Height = height,
            Width = width
        }
    };
return writer.Write(textForEncoding);
}
public Texture2D generateQR(string text) {
    var encoded = new Texture2D (256, 256);
    var color32 = Encode(text, encoded.width, encoded.height);
    encoded.SetPixels32(color32);
    encoded.Apply();
    return encoded;
}
```

Вешаю картинку на RawImagе, забитую в поле

```
public RawImage RI;

RI.texture = generateQR("https://test.link/123");
```

На выходе имею картинку с здоровенными белыми бордерами.

[image: QR-код с большими белыми границами]

- Q1 - Как их убрать белые бордеры?
- Q2 - Есть ли возможность сделать прозрачный бекграунд?
- Q3 - Как заменить черный цвет кода, на другой?

Comment: Во избежание ошибочного чтения кода я бы на вашем месте не стал бы изменять цвет фона и тона самого кода. Что касается полей, никто не запрещает сделать его больше, а текстуру обрезать по краям.

Comment: @aepot А как обрезать эту текстуру? Так-же насчет цветов - вопрос больше теоретический, но очень хочу знать на него ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q3: Пример изменения цвета фона и тона:

```
    private static Color32[] Encode(string textForEncoding, int width, int height)
    {
        var writer = new BarcodeWriter
        {
            Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,

            Options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions
            {
                Height = height,
                Width = width
            },
            Renderer = new Color32Renderer
            {
                Background = new Color32(255, 0, 0, 0),
                Foreground = new Color32(0, 255, 0, 0)
            }
        };
        return writer.Write(textForEncoding);
    }
```

Q2: Я не полностью уверен, но следующий пример должен создать прозрачный фон:

```
    private static Color32[] Encode(string textForEncoding, int width, int height)
    {
        var writer = new BarcodeWriter
        {
            Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,

            Options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions
            {
                Height = height,
                Width = width
            },
            Renderer = new Color32Renderer
            {
                Background = new Color32(0, 0, 0, 255)
            }
        };
        return writer.Write(textForEncoding);
    }
```

Q1: Создайте изображение как можно меньше размером, затем измените размер вручную

```
    private static Color32[] Encode(string textForEncoding, int width, int height)
    {
        var writer = new BarcodeWriter
        {
            Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,

            Options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions
            {
                Height = width,
                Width = height,
                Margin = 0
            }
        };
        return writer.Write(textForEncoding);
    }
    public Texture2D generateQR(string text)
    {
        // create the image as small as possible without a white border by setting width an height to 1
        var color32 = Encode(text, 1, 1);
        var widthAndHeight = color32.Length / 2;
        var encoded = new Texture2D(widthAndHeight, widthAndHeight);
        encoded.SetPixels32(color32);
        encoded.Apply();
        //
        // Attention: insert code for resizing to the desired size here
        // I didn't try it myself. Not sure if it works.
        //
        encoded.Resize(256, 256);
        return encoded;
    }
```

Comment: Здесь принято задавать вопросы и давать ответы только на русском языке.

Comment: Извините, в будущем я больше не буду отвечать на вопросы.

Comment: Ваше право, я лишь к тому, какие здесь действуют правила. Если вам хочется постить только на английском, есть основная англоязычная площадка для этого.